# Find 2 nearest values in 2 arrays matching the x,y coordinates

Tags: python, arrays

I have to find 2 different values in 2 arrays in python. It don't gives me such problems but the 2 values have to being in the same x,y coordinates and I've no idea how to deal with that.

For example : I must find the closest number of 5 in the first array and 87 in the second but x and y must have the same values.

For the moment, I've done the average between the two x and y values of each array. But the results are not precise at all.

Have you got any ideas how to deal with that?

EDIT :
There is my code :

```
#This is two arrays that I extract from a file. It contains a lot of values corresponding to latitude and longitude on a earth's photograph.

latitude = data.get_band('latitude').read_as_array(width, height, 0, 0)
longitude = data.get_band('longitude').read_as_array(width, height, 0, 0)
idx = (np.abs(latitude-lat0)).argmin()
nearest_lat = latitude.flat[idx]
idx_lat = np.unravel_index(idx, latitude.shape)
idx = (np.abs(longitude-lon0)).argmin()
nearest_lon =  longitude.flat[idx]
idx_lon = np.unravel_index(idx, longitude.shape)
```

EDIT 2:
Finally, i used another way to do that :

```
            latitude = data.get_band('latitude').read_as_array(width, height, 0, 0)
        longitude = data.get_band('longitude').read_as_array(width, height, 0, 0)
        dist = (latitude - lat0)**2 + (longitude - lon0)**2
        idx = np.argmin(dist)
        idx = np.unravel_index(idx, latitude.shape)
        PIXELCOL = idx[0]
        PIXELROWS = idx[1]
```

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the 2 values have to being in the same x,y coordinates"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your [chances to get useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [show us your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what is the relation between x,y and these two arrays and two different numbers?!!

Comment: I have two arrays and two different numbers that represents geographic coordinates. One value represent one pixel. I have to pick one pixel who has the closest values from those that the user has enter

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could `zip` the `latitude` and `longitude` lists, giving you tuples of coordinates. Then find the `min` of those w.r.t. the Euclidian distance to your reference coordinate.

```
>>> lat0, lon0 = 23, 42
>>> latitude = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(50)]
>>> longitude = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(50)]
>>> min(zip(latitude, longitude), key=lambda t: (t[0]-lat0)**2 + (t[1]-lon0)**2)
(21, 38)
```

Or if you also need the index (which would be the same for `x` and `y`, use `enumerate`:

```
>>> min(enumerate(zip(latitude, longitude)), key=lambda t: (t[1][0]-lat0)**2 + (t[1][1]-lon0)**2)
(13, (21, 38))
```

Some notes:

- Actually, [Euclidian distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) also involves a square root, but for just finding the closest coordinates, you do not need to compute it; if `x` is minimal, so is `sqrt(x)`
- As noted in comments, using Euclidian distance is not entirely correct, as the earth is a sphere. However, it should be a good-enough approximation for locations that are not thousands of miles apart, at the poles, around the date line, or in R'lyeh. If any of this should be the case, you can use the much more complicated [Great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

Comment: Why the Euclidean distance?  Why not the geodesic distance?  The OP needs to tell us what he's seeking.  (Also, you've got the square of the Euclidean distance.)

Comment: @saulspatz Well, I just guesses the distance metric based on "longitude" and "latitude". About the square root: It's not needed for finding the min, so I omitted it.

Comment: What I mean is that the Euclidean distance isn't appropriate for finding the distance between two points on a sphere, unless they're very close together.  The Euclidean distance could be used to find which two points are closest, but not how far apart they are.

Comment: @saulspatz Sure, that's true, but (1) the actual distance is not needed, just which is closest, (2) I'd assume the points to be rather close, and not at the poles, and (3), let something for OP to find out. ;-)

Comment: OK.  I can't tell for sure what the OP really wants to compute, so I have nothing more to add.